# ElasticBeanstalk load balancer with non 80/443 port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed on ElasticBeanstalk. It is a web server, with load balancer in front of it. I have configured the load balancer to listen to port 443 from `ElasticBeanstalk > "My Application" > Configuration > Networking`. But I also need to open port 444 to listen for https connections and forward them again to port 80 on the ElasticBeanstalk app container. There isn't such config option in ElasticBeanstalk networking configuration panel.

I however found the load balancer of my EB instance in `EC2 > Load Balancers`. There I added an HTTPS listener on 444, listening on 80 of the instance but it seems that this is not working... Any suggestions how would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured it out on my own.

The issue was that my ElasticBeanstalk LoadBalancer wasn't in a VPC. In order to be able to access non 80/443 ports, you have to create the instance in a VPC then make an allow inbound rule for each non-standard port and finally go to `EC2 > Load Balancers > Select <your specific elastic beanstalk balancer> > Listeners > add the port mappings`.